# Create React App integration with ReactJS.net

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, create-react-app, reactjs.net

I'm trying to set up a asp.net mvc project integrating a create react app and reactjs.net. Trying to follow the tutorial [here](https://reactjs.net/bundling/webpack.html) but facing this exception

```
ReactJS.NET has not been initialised correctly. Please ensure you have called services.AddReact() and app.UseReact() in your Startup.cs file. (ReactNotInitialisedException)
ReactNotInitialisedException at React.ReactEnvironment.get_GetCurrentOrThrow()
    No JS engines were registered. Visit https://reactjs.net/docs for more information. (ReactException)
```

This is my ReactConfig file. I have tried some combinations here to not load react and set JS engines.

```
ReactSiteConfiguration.Configuration
              .SetLoadBabel(false)
              .SetLoadReact(false)
              .SetReactAppBuildPath("~/ClientApp/build");
JsEngineSwitcher.Current.DefaultEngineName = V8JsEngine.EngineName;
            JsEngineSwitcher.Current.EngineFactories.AddV8();
```

This is my layout cshtml.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello React</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body className="">
    <div id="content"></div>
    @Html.React("Components.App", new{p1 = "value"})
</body>
</html>
```

From the tutorial, instead of expose-components.js, I'm doing the same in my default index.js as this would be the default entry point for the create react app and I did not want to eject it. I do not have a startup.cs file in my MVC project instead have a Global.ascx.cs

Comment: After a bit of random fiddling with JSEngine Im also getting this error
    Unable to resolve type: React.JavaScriptEngineFactory (TinyIoCResolutionException)
    The relative virtual path \x27static/js/main.9185afe4.js\x27 is not allowed here. (ArgumentException)
ArgumentException at System.Web.VirtualPath.FailIfRelativePath()